# How to use $.each() to create a dynamic tooltip in datepicker Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery datepicker where I list all holidays and display the name of each holiday in a tooltip during hover effect.
But I'm facing a bug, everything works normally when I use a for loop to display my tooltip, but when I try to use $.each() my tooltip doesn't work, here's my code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var dmy = "";
        dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-";
        dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-";
        dmy += d.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, enableDays) >= 0) {   
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                if(item.date == dmy){
                    console.log('forEach: ', item)
                    return [true, 'highlight', item.name];
                }
            })                                
            /*             
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                                
                if (data[i].date == dmy) {     
                    console.log('for: ', data[i])
                    return [true, 'highlight', data[i].name];
                }
            } 
            */                                                         
            return [true, ''];                                                                                              
        }
        else {
            return [false, ""];
        }
    }
});
```

This what my $.each() returns in the console with the names of the holidays, it went through three times.
[image]

And this is what the console returns when I use the for loop:

[image]

Comment: (Offtopic...) why don't you use an [ISO compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format?

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple:

`return` inside a **for loop** *will* stop execution and **exit the function** with that *returned* value (`[true, 'highlight', item.name]` in your case) — which BTW is expected for the [`beforeShowDay` function to return with an array to work properly](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).

jQuery's [**$.each**(iterable, callback(index[, item]))](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), will iterate over all the iterable set (Array) **without stopping** **unless you use `return false;`**.

The returned array you're using is enclosed inside its own `callback` scope — but **not** in the outer `beforeShowDay` function scope. Therefore you see all the logs, but the `$.each` didn't stopped with a return that would ultimately exit the `beforeShowDay` function. It ultimately always exits with the `return [true, '']` Array.

To make it work with a `$.each` use:

```js
let result = [true, ""]; // Default

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
  if (item.date == dmy) {
    result = [true, 'highlight', item.name]; // Modify it!
    return false; // Exit $.each loop
  }
});

return result; // Return Default or Modified
```

Here's the above implemented in your example:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var dmy = "";
    dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-";
    dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-";
    dmy += d.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, enableDays) >= 0) {
      let result = [true, ""]; // Default

      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        if (item.date == dmy) {
          result = [true, 'highlight', item.name]; // Modify it!
          return false; // Exit $.each loop
        }
      });

      return result; // Return Default or Modified
    } else {
      return [false, ""];
    }
  }
});
```